# function encrypt file - input & output to same file in python

Tags: python, pycrypto

i have this script : http://pastebin.com/JypqErN5
in this moment the function working input output file :

```
encrypt_file(in_file, out_file, password):
```

need input output to same file, simile to this :

```
encrypt_file(in_file, password):
```

im try to make same name input output bat not encrypt file correctly.

the function is this :

```
def encrypt_file(input_file, output_file, password):
    with open(input_file, 'rb') as in_file, open(output_file, 'wb') as out_file:
        encrypt(in_file, out_file, password)
```

how can i make this edits ? thanks all

Comment: Use the existing function to write to a tempfile. If all goes well, rename and delete.

Comment: Your pastebin link doesn't work. Consider pasting the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't generally read from and write to a file at the same time.

So, you have two basic options.

---

First, you can read into memory, then encrypt, then write back out. Hopefully you have an `encrypt` function that works on strings rather than files. Since you've tagged this `pycrypto`, and all of its engines work on strings, this should be trivial. But if you have to use files, you can usually use [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) (or, for 2.x, `cStringIO.StringIO`), which wraps up a byte string in a file-like object, like this:

```
def encrypt_file(path, password):
    temp = io.BytesIO()
    with open(path, 'rb') as in_file:
        encrypt(in_file, temp, password)
    with open(path, 'wb') as out_file:
        out_file.write(temp.getvalue())
```

This is dead simple, but of course it could be a problem if your files are gigantic.

---

Or you can write to a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), then [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace) the original file with the temporary:

```
def encrypt_file(path, password):
    dir = os.path.dirname(path)
    with open(path, 'rb') as in_file, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=dir, delete=False) as out_file:
        encrypt(in_file, temp, password)
    os.replace(temp.name, path)
```

This has some major advantages over the other method—it doesn't necessarily take a ton of memory (that depends on how `encrypt` is written), and there's no chance of leaving behind a partially-written file if you pull the plug (`os.replace` is atomic—it either happens completely, or not at all). But it's a little more complicated. And, before Python 3.3, there was no `replace` function. On Unix, `rename` works just as well. On Windows… well, that's a whole mess.